# SQL returning decrypted password

Tags: java, mysql, sql, encryption

I made a method to return the decrypted password from my database yet i get an error saying the table 'password' doesnt exist or aes_DECRYPT(username, password) doesnt exist. No idea why because it has worked before.

```
public String selectOldPassword(String username){
    String oldPassword = "";
    try{
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, username) FROM userdetails WHERE username = ?");
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet passwordData = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(passwordData.next()){
            oldPassword = passwordData.getString("AES_DECRYPT(password,username)");
            System.out.println(oldPassword);
        }
        stmt.close();
        connect.close();
    }catch(SQLException sql){
        sql.printStackTrace();
    }
    return oldPassword;
}
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mysql Workbench

Answer (score 1):

I would use an alias in the select:

> stmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, username) as decrypted_password FROM userdetails WHERE username = ?");

And read the values from the ResultSet.

> oldPassword = passwordData.getString("decrypted_password");

I honestly do not know if JDBC allows columns names like

> AES_DECRYPT(password, username)

I do have to add that I cannot think of a good reason to decrypt passwords from a database. Seems like asking for security breaches to me.

Comment: Thank you the alias works.  And it's for my school project so I can change the password if needed

Comment: @user3511446 No problem ;-). As an aside, the right way to change the password would be to insert the correct encrypted value into the database directly.

Comment: thank you.  I've done that for inserting it I just haven't shown it  on that wasn't a problem. I will keep that in mind